# How to update two tables with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql

I would like to insert into database new customer.
 To do that I have to put in table CLIENT FirstName, LastName, Postcode. To second table CLIENTGROUP I have to put customer group, like Visitor or VIP. First Tables Id is foreign key in second.

When I put a new customer in CLIENT id is increased automatically. How to make a query that would updated id in CLIENTGROUP?
I will have to join two query

```
        var connection = OpenConnection();
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "insert into Klient(FirstName,LastName,Postcode) values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Postcode)";
        AddParameterString(command, "@FirstName", model.FirstName);
        AddParameterString(command, "@LastName", model.LastName);
        AddParameterDecimal(command, "@Turnover", model.Postcode);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = "insert into ClientGroup (ClientGroup) values (@ClientGroup)";
        AddParameterString(command, "@ClientGroup", model.ClienGroup);"                        
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but I simply have no Idea how.

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to the first insert query, that would give you id of inserted customer. Use `ExecuteScalar` method on c# side (if you use ADO.NET). Query:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (/*...*/) VALUES (/*...*/)
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

c#:

```
var connection = OpenConnection();
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"
    insert into Klient(FirstName,LastName,Postcode) values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Postcode)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

AddParameterString(command, "@FirstName", model.FirstName);
AddParameterString(command, "@LastName", model.LastName);
AddParameterDecimal(command, "@Turnover", model.Postcode);

int customerId = (int) command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// ...use customerId in the second insert
```

You might also consider wrapping these two insert queries with transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this. Also assuming `ClientId` is the name of your primary key column . Also set auto increment off for your foreign key (in `ClientGroup` table).

```
    var connection = OpenConnection();
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "insert into Klient(FirstName,LastName,Postcode) values (@FirstName, @LastName, @Postcode) Select Ident_Current('Klient')";
    AddParameterString(command, "@FirstName", model.FirstName);
    AddParameterString(command, "@LastName", model.LastName);
    AddParameterDecimal(command, "@Turnover", model.Postcode);

    int foreignKey = command.ExecuteScaler();

    command.CommandText = "insert into ClientGroup (ClientId,ClientGroup) values (@ClientId, @ClientGroup)";
    AddParameterString(command, "@ClientId", foreignKey);
    AddParameterString(command, "@ClientGroup", model.ClienGroup);                        
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@identity` or `ident_current`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)